# How can I start from the 'left' chart point data when chart have one or two data?

Tags: javascript, highcharts

We're using Highcharts to display some data.
Problem is, when we only have one data point on chart, it is aligned in the middle.
Here sample [image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9DZ4Y.png).

Is it possible to make it start from left, not in the middle? I need that horizonal axis data point is started from 'left'.
[This image is sample of what I want to do.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xNQ65.png)

`Sample source` : https://jsfiddle.net/Lucius08/ufxqdrj9/165/

Comment: Hi, thanks for example but I do not really know what you want to achieve, could you simplified demo, you can use one of these [demos](https://www.highcharts.com/demo/gantt) as a template.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.